# eclipse cdt: calling make file from command line and adding version number

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt, embedded-linux

two simple questions:

how do i call eclipse cdt generated make file with all the environment variable ? for example, my make file is generated at location PROJECT_FOLDER_ROOT/Debug/makefile , and if i try to call it:

```
khan@khan-P55A-UD3P:~/git/gcc/libGCC/Debug$ make -k -j5 all
```

> Building file: ../src/utility/Versioning.cpp
>   Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
>   mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++ -I/home/khan/carambola.pristine/staging_dir/target-mipsel_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/utility/Versioning.d" -MT"src/utility/Versioning.d" -o "src/utility/Versioning.o" "../src/utility/Versioning.cpp"
>   /bin/sh: 1: mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++: not found
>   make: *** [src/utility/Versioning.o] Error 127
>   make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

it is looking for `mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++` , which is an environment variable for the eclipse build system . how to include it in the command line usage?

second question: 
is there any way to automatically increment build number in CDT ? google search was not helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

right after asking here, it managed to figure out the eclipse makefile issue:

i wrote this script to do it. hope it helps someone:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_PATH=$PWD
DEBUG_FOLDER_PATH=$CURRENT_PATH/Debug
TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/home/khan/carambola.pristine/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_r2_gcc-4.7-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin


cd $DEBUG_FOLDER_PATH


export CWD=$DEBUG_FOLDER_PATH
export PWD=$DEBUG_FOLDER_PATH
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH

echo $CWD
echo $PWD
echo $PATH


make -k -j5 $1 $2 $3 $4
```

however, i am still looking for a way to increment build number somehow. any help would be appreciated.

thnkyou

Comment: basically eclipse uses 3 variables , cwd , pwd , path